# How to calculate non centrality parameter?

Tags: distributions, multinomial-distribution, chi-squared-distribution, non-central

> Suppose $Y\sim N_p(\mu,\sigma^2I_p)$. Let $A$ be a symmetric
>   idempotent matrix. I want to show $Y^{T}AY$ follows a chi-sq distribution with some non
>   centrality parameter.

Suppose $tr(A)=r(A)=k$. Note that $A=P^{T}\Delta P$ where $P$ is orthogonal and $\Delta$ is diagonal. WLOG assume first $k$ elements of $\Delta$ are $1$.
Then $Z:=PY \sim N_p(P\mu,\sigma^2I_p)$

$Y^{T}AY=Z^{T}\Delta Z$= $\sum_{i=1}^{k} Z_i^2$ which is evidently a chisq distribution by [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_chi-squared_distribution#Background) definition. And the non centrality parameter is
$$\frac1{\sigma^2}\sum_{i=1}^{k}[(P\mu)_i]^2$$
But this representation is very inconvenient. Is there better representation of the above?